# MATLAB algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing, average, moving-average

So I need to improve segmentation on an image. This is done by a really easy and straight-forward algorithm which is the following -

Loop through the whole image (the green channel of img.jpg) For each pixel, P

- Compute the average grey value of the 21 by 21 pixel region centred
  on P, call it A
- Multiply the value of P by 128/A

I am unsure about how to write the code, since I am new to Matlab (started learning it today basically).
Any suggestions on how to implement the algorithm correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
f = imread('img.jpg');
greenChannel = f(:,:,2);

h = fspecial('average', 21);  %%// Kernel to be used for averaging
%h = ones(21,21)/(21*21); %%// Same as above, but custom-made
A = imfilter(greenChannel,h); %%// Average values for each pixel

newgreenChannel = greenChannel.*(128./A);
figure,imshow(newgreenChannel)
```

Comment: Don't we need to go through all the pixels (2 for loops?)?

Comment: `imfilter` internally goes through all the pixels in loops. It's basically an optimized version of doing so, I believe.

Comment: Look at the `imfilter` documentation for more info - http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imfilter.html